# No NFC Device detected

Tags: nfc, rfid, pcsc, acr122, lib-nfc

I have trouble using my "uTrust 4701 F Dual Interface Reader" because is not recognized as NFC device while trying to read from Mifare Classic. I installed "libnfc" library from git repository with followings commands:

```
/configure --with-drivers=all --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc
make
make install
```

When I launch "nfc-list" command, I'm getting:

```
debug   libnfc.config   Unable to open directory: /etc/nfc/devices.d
debug   libnfc.general  log_level is set to 3
debug   libnfc.general  allow_autoscan is set to true
debug   libnfc.general  allow_intrusive_scan is set to false
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) defined by user
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.8.0
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using acr122_usb driver
debug   libnfc.general  0 device(s) found using pn53x_usb driver
No NFC device found.
```

but using "pcsc_scan" command, I'm getting:

```
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.6.2 (c) 2001-2022, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: Identiv Identiv uTrust 4701 F Dual Interface Reader [uTrust 4701 F Contact Reader] (55041707200298) 00 00
1: Identiv Identiv uTrust 4701 F Dual Interface Reader [uTrust 4701 F CL Reader] (55041707200298) 01 00
 
Sat Sep 16 16:21:46 2023
 Reader 0: Identiv Identiv uTrust 4701 F Dual Interface Reader [uTrust 4701 F Contact Reader] (55041707200298) 00 00
  Event number: 0
  Card state: Card removed, 
 Reader 1: Identiv Identiv uTrust 4701 F Dual Interface Reader [uTrust 4701 F CL Reader] (55041707200298) 01 00
  Event number: 0
  Card state: Card removed, 
   
Sat Sep 16 16:21:58 2023
 Reader 1: Identiv Identiv uTrust 4701 F Dual Interface Reader [uTrust 4701 F CL Reader] (55041707200298) 01 00
  Event number: 1
  Card state: Card inserted, 
  ATR: 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A

ATR: 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention
+ T0 = 8F, Y(1): 1000, K: 15 (historical bytes)
  TD(1) = 80 --> Y(i+1) = 1000, Protocol T = 0 
-----
  TD(2) = 01 --> Y(i+1) = 0000, Protocol T = 1 
-----
+ Historical bytes: 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00
  Category indicator byte: 80 (compact TLV data object)
    Tag: 4, len: F (initial access data)
      Initial access data: 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00
+ TCK = 6A (correct checksum)

Possibly identified card (using /usr/share/pcsc/smartcard_list.txt):
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 .. 00 01 00 00 00 00 ..
        MIFARE Classic 1K (as per PCSC std part3)
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 .. .. 00 00 00 00 ..
        RFID - ISO 14443 Type A Part 3 (as per PCSC std part3)
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
        NXP/Philips MIFARE Classic 1K (as per PCSC std part3)
        http://www.nxp.com/#/pip/pip=[pfp=41863]|pp=[t=pfp,i=41863]
        Oyster card - Transport for London (first-gen)
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oyster_card
        ACOS5/1k Mirfare
        vivotech ViVOcard Contactless Test Card
        Bangkok BTS Sky SmartPass
        Mifare Classic 1K (block 0 re-writeable)
        Electic vehicle charging card of the German Telekom, acting as EMSP GetCharge
        Electic vehicle charging card of the EMSP Stadtwerke Muenchen (SWM), ladenetz.de, Germany
        Electic vehicle charging card of the EMSP EinfachStromLaden of Maingau-Energie, Germany
        Scouter carsharing customer card in Germany
        https://scouter.de/
        DKV Euro Service +charge (Transport)
        https://www.dkv-mobility.com/en/fuelling/fuel-card/dkv-card-charge/
        Andante (Transport)
```

I have this content:

```
blacklist pn533_usb
blacklist pn533
blacklist nfc
```

in 2 files:

1. /etc/modprobe.d/nfc-blacklist.conf
2. /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-libnfc.conf

I am on Kali Linux and this is my "lsusb":

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04e6:5724 SCM Microsystems, Inc. Identiv uTrust 4701 F Dual Interface Reader
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1d57:ad05 Xenta HID compliant-mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 145f:0203 Trust Trust USB Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0016 SiGma Micro USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 275d:0ba6  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
```

Why is it not recognized in nfc-list devices? Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

The debug output indicates that only the `acr122_usb` and `pn53x_usb` drivers were tried. This is identical to the behavior of the standard Debian-packaged version of the library, so apparently the system is still using the packaged version of the library. Your library build or installation steps must have failed somehow.

You haven't included the output from the build and installation commands, so it will be impossible for us to figure out exactly what went wrong.